# Hidden Surface Removal C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove the hidden surfaces on a cube rotating around its own diagonal axis and around general `y`-axis.

I am using  `gluLookAt(0, 0, 20,    0, 0, 1,   0, 10, 0)` for the view stuff.

However, it doesn't entirely produce a well removed surfaces.

I am calculating the normal vector by:

```
GLfloat CalculateVectorNormal(GLfloat fVert1[], GLfloat fVert2[], GLfloat fVert3[], GLfloat fNormalZ)
{
GLfloat Qx, Qy, Qz, Px, Py, Pz;

   Qx = fVert2[0]-fVert1[0];
   Qy = fVert2[1]-fVert1[1];
   Qz = fVert2[2]-fVert1[2];
   Px = fVert3[0]-fVert1[0];
   Py = fVert3[1]-fVert1[1];
   Pz = fVert3[2]-fVert1[2];

   fNormalZ = (Px*Qy - Py*Qx);
   return fNormalZ;   
}
```

and I am checking if `fNormalZ` values is less than 0. I think I am making a mistake with the view stuff. I believe I am looking from only `-z` axis. That's why I just check for `fNormalZ`.

I can't play with view a lot either since then I lose the cube from sight.

Any help is appreciated. I really need some urgent help.
Thank you very much in advance.

(Homework question, gl functions not allowed.)

Comment: Is my view vector is (0,0,20)? Should I also consider other vectors to find out the view vector, which I will crossproduct with the normal vector?

Comment: I don't have OpenGL to play with, but I see 4 problems: 1) you don't say what's wrong with the results, 2) you don't seem to know where your camera and object are, or what a view vector is, 3) you are *trying to optimize something that doesn't yet work* (a classic), and 4) your `CalculateVectorNormal` does not follow mathematical convention, so the result is the negative of what it should be (should be (`2`-`1`)x(`3`-`2`), not (`3`-`1`)x(`2`x`1`)).

Answer (score 0):

A normal is a vector, not a scalar. You should calculate the components for X, Y *and* Z and return that.

You need to *subtract* the camera position (and inversely apply its rotation) to the face coordinates before calculating the vector. You then do a dotProduct between one of the points and the calculated normal to find the angle of the face. If the angle is less than zero, it's facing away from the camera viewpoint, and can be culled.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you very much but I already know how to calculate the normal vector. I am using a scalar because I think -x and -y values are zero in the normal vector, which will make the x and y values in the cross product zeros.

Comment: @Sammy: Why do you think that? I bet you're wrong. This is probably why it's failing...

Comment: @Sammy: See my edit for a description of how to apply camera position too. I realised that you need dot product, not magnitude (obviously how can magnitude be -1.. duh!).

Comment: Well, I have 3 vectors for view: Position, view and up-vector. And I don't know how to calculate a view vector out of those 3 vectors.

Comment: I mean, gluLookat consists of 3 vectors. If we should consider only the first 2 ones, then my view vector would be (0,0,20)-(0,0,1)=(0,0,19). And when I dotproduct this with any vector, x and y values will be zero . Right?

Comment: @Sammy: I no longer have any clue what you're asking. Let's just focus on one problem at a time, ok?